# Is there a way to use 100% of the edge to go between monitors of different resolutions?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

So I have two monitors, my main is a 37" 16:9 1080p screen (my old TV), and the other is a 20" 4:3 LCD.  Now by a nice coincidence, when the 20" one is rotated portrait, it's height is about the same as the 37" LCD.  Since they line up, I'd like the mouse to be able to move back and forth along the entire height of the 20" one, but because it's 1600px high and the 37" is 1080px high there's a solid 1/3 of the screen that the mouse will just not go past.

I know it's a minor issue, but it's a bit annoying.  Is there any program I can download or a setting I can change that will make 100% of the edge traversable rather than limiting it to the height of the shorter side pixelwise?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you mean. If you right click on your desktop, and select "Screen resolution", you can see 2 monitors in a sort of preview. Drag your 2nd monitor up or down inside this preview.

This way, you can as an example, align up the top of the monitors, this way, the mouse will not collide when you move it alongside the top. It will however collide in the bottom then.
To my knowledge, this (and aligning them at the bottom, for the opposite effect) is the only way to do it, and there's no way to make the cursor jump up or down, so it moves fluidly.

To achieve this, a piece of software will have to be made. I am a programmer in .Net, let me know if you really want this, and I'll try to figure something out :)

Comment: It's more of a minor annoyance...  I was hoping there was a registry tweak or an existing program to do it.  If no one else expresses an interest, it's probably not worth your time to code it unless it's super easy.  Thanks though!

Comment: Hah, my time is worthless. I might see what I can do one of these days. I'll try to contact you when I have ^^